# Xamarin vs native iOS and Android

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin

Here I need some developer opinion. I tested xamarin studio to build android and iOS app, and on first it was great. But later I discovered that i still need so much of xcode and eclipse here to help me with front end to bring it up, and at some point it was pain in the ass on backend. So it was jumping around little bit. So I decided to build apps in native platforms and wait community to grow. Does anyone here had performance issue on Android apps built with xamarin at aspect of lot of async and medium large data work, native app is quiet a bit faster and stable from that aspect.? Am I wrong here, should i wait a little bit for Xamarin to grab the traction ?

Comment: Funny how the questions that get closed for this reason are still so useful ;-)

Comment: The question is adequate. A beginner always wants to compare development platforms: e.g. Android Studio VS Xamarin IDE VS etc.

Answer (score 13):

There are hardly any performance issues that i have observed in an app developed in xamarin. Except the bugs about Xamarin studio that are already reported in their Bugzilla, rest all works great. I have used both xamarin studio as well as visual studio for developing apps for Android and IOS. 
However developing for ios, its better done in Xamarin studio in mac because you need to pair a windows machine to a Mac if you want to have the simulator and proper debugging there. Xcode and Xamarin studio actually need to be used together for this. Android, i never needed to use eclipse. And as you have mono working for you, things even turn out to work faster as now not all things are thrown at dalvik. Mono manages all that it can, and Dalvik comes into picture only for things that explicitly need dalvik and android. Xamarin is growning steadily and support also is too good. It is already being widely used. No need to wait for anything. Just dive in and enjoy the newness of coding for Android and ios in something different.
Cheers. :)

Comment: Plenty of performance issues. You just have to do anything beyond a cookie cutter app.

Comment: This is an answer that is not "opinion based" and touches all points.

Comment: "[...] and support also is too good." -I believe, you meant to say "very good" :-)

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion Xamarin is just great.

I'm using it in Visual Studio 2012 and I've made iOS & Android apps.
The result is a native app so performances are the same.
The only point that disturbing me with iOS apps is when I want to modify the Info.plist in Visual Studio (add app icons for example) or to deploy app on the AppStore, it never works as I want so I make it in Xamarin Studio (or Xcode) on Mac.
However, Visual Studio is so much better to use compared to Xamarin Studio & Eclipse that my choice is done.

Comment: Doesn't Xamarin expire after a certain time?

Comment: You have to renew license every year, but apps already on store still work.

Comment: Xamarin is now free!